Difference in desktop site & mobile site's view of sliding gallery
I've been trying to get this thing to work for a while now, but it's been giving me headaches.
(Not an experienced coder here), But i was able to add a sliding gallery to my site : https://www.spectrumtheories.com/products and it looks perfectly fine on mobile :

then on desktop the width of the gallery is reduced :

so what i added on the gallery css's location was : overflow: unset;
which fixed it well on desktop. Now i can see the full gallery covering the whole page correctly.
But now when i get on mobile, the page goes towards the right when scrolling down & ofcourse my way of fixing is adding overflow-x: hidden; to the body of my css, but on mobile it still doesn't work.. The site still scrolls to the right, if anyone could help me with this issue that would be amazing as this is very frustrating!

Not sure I'm getting you. There seems to be no problem at all at my end

Please put relevant code in the question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-exaumple

I'll add an example of how the site looks on desktop & mobile, one sec

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example *
